# ASP.NET MVC 2 and AutoMapper - dissecting and mapping uploaded file info with AutoMapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, automapper

This is the 3rd major edit to this question, so I'm going to write a quick little summary first, then ask the question.

I have an input/edit model I'm planning on using with an EF4-backed MVC 2 site.  The model is as follows:

```
public class AdminGameEditModel
{
    [Required]
    public int GameID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="A game must have a title")]
    public string GameTitle { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="A short URL must be supplied")]
    public string ShortURL { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="A box art image must be supplied")]
    public HttpPostedFileBase BoxArt { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="A large image for the index page is required")]
    public HttpPostedFileBase IndexImage { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="A game must have a review")]
    public string ReviewText { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="A game must have a score")]
    public int ReviewScore { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="A game must have at least one Pro listed")]
    public string[] Pros { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="A game must have at least one Con listed")]
    public string[] Cons { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="A game must belong to a genre")]
    public int GenreID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="A game must be associated with at least one platform")]
    public int[] PlatformIDs { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like to map it to a Game entity for creation/updating.  There's a snag, though - I need to save the images in a particular folder, and then take their paths and save *those* as properties in my entity.  So, an example for clarity's sake: rather than my Game entity having a actual BoxArt image, it would instead have the path to the correct BoxArt image.  I hope this makes sense.  Let me know if I need to clarify.

Can I do this with AutoMapper?  If so, can anyone provide some code guidance?

---

EDIT:

Part of the problem is that my model is fairly complex, as it contains a many-to-many relationship.  The PlatformIDs are ultimately used to build/rebuild (depending whether I'm creating or updating an entity) linked Platform entities in the Game/Platform map.  I'm not sure if AutoMapper can do something that complex without needing to go through my repository.

Then there's the problem of the image paths.  The paths aren't a property of `HttpPostedFileBase`, but must be constructed by hand like so:

```
if (BoxArt.ContentLength > 0) {
    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(BoxArt.FileName);
    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/BoxArt"), fileName);
    BoxArt.SaveAs(path);
}
```

So, what I'm looking for is more complex than just trying to map simple properties across objects.  I'd like to keep a reference to my edit model *out* of my repository.  Separation of concerns, and all that.  Because of that, I need to map to an entity before I attempt to pass it to my repo for saving.  I'm just not sure how to do it without blending app layers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you, all you need to do is update your properties first prior to the call to AutoMapper.

Make sure your object has the correct values prior to calling AutoMapper.

After the call to do the mapping, your destination object will have all the matching properties copied over.

Post some more code if this doesn't answer the questoin.